# Making an html element created using javascript "required"

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, required

```
var textbox = function(me) {
    if (me.checked == false) {
        var textb = document.createElement('textarea');

        textb.name = "Address";
        textb.id = "Address";
        textb.required;
        textb.placeholder = "Address";
        me.parentNode.appendChild(textb);
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        if (me.checked == false) {
            me.parentNode.removeChild(textb);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

This is the the java script code that I wrote to display a text area (named textb) when a radio button is selected. Though I put "textb.required" the text area is not made a compulsory field (that is if a person selects the radio button and does not fill the address an error is not returned)

Please help me to correct this

Comment: try textb.required=true

Comment: (Just as a tip, please from now on write "java script" as "javascript".)

Comment: Thanx mate it worked;